# What is the ruby `Object#freeze` correspondent in C++?

Tags: c++, freeze

`freeze` method, which makes an object dynamically becomes a constant. Is there a way to achieve this in C++? like first give value to a `std::string`, then lock it to prevent further modifications.

Comment: Like `const std::string s = "Hello world!";` ?

Comment: There is no general *dynamic* equivalent; you usually use constant objects for similar purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the object as **[const](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/const_cv_qualifier.htm)**.

By using the `const` qualifier you can initialize the object while creating it & any attempts to modify that object during the course of the program will lead to Undefined Behavior, which basically means users are forbidden from modifying it, this will simulate the *freeze* effect you are looking for.

Comment: what if I want to change the string twice, after which I want to turn it const?

Comment: @P.S.V.R: Not possible.What I mentioned in the answer is what you can get in standard C++.